# In VS Code, is there a way to go next line per two or three with shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to go to next/previous line in VS Code. But it sometimes makes me feel dull because it has the cursor go just one line when I want to browse the file casually.

Is there a way to have the cursor go few lines or other more quick way to browse file (like go to next class or method definition)?

Comment: If you use the vim mode, then `j` and `k` are used to move one line up and down respectively, so`10j` will move 10 rows down, and `10k`, up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

## Jumping Lines in V.S. Code

---

##### V.S. Code Keyboard Shortcuts

---

> **V.S. Code** offers its users the ability to customize **Keyboard Shortcuts** using navigational type commands that move the cursor, via the *"keybindings.json"* configuration file. When the *"keybindings.json"* file is configured properly you are able to use **Keyboard Shortcuts** to jump up **`n`-lines**, jump down **`n`-lines**, jump left **`n`-chars**, or to jump right **`n`-chars**.
>
> - **NOTE:** ***"`n` can equal any number".***

#### Getting Started

---

> To navigate the cursor in the fashoin that this topic covers, you will need to configure a few customized **V.S. Code Keybindings** (aka Keyboard Shortcuts). If this is not somthing that you have done before you don't need to worry. Binding a shortcut to a unique combonation of keys is actually quite simple, and it can be whimsical as well. It certainly will improve your **V.S. Code experiance**.
>
> ###### To get started creating your *"line-jumping"*  **Keyboard Shortcuts** follow the instructions below. If you need any extra help during the *keybinding creation process* you can use the official **V.S. Code**, community maintained, documentation as a guide. I have posted the link below:
>
> ##### [V.S. Code: Keyboard Shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

1. – Use the <kbd>F1</kbd> Key to open your **"Quick Input Drop-Down Menu"**
2. – Type "Keyboard Shortcut" into the **"Quick Input Menu"**.
3. – Select **"Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)"**

###### Note: There will be two *"Keyboard Shortcut"* options that you will be able to choose from. One of the options will read default, and one **WILL NOT** read default. Make sure to select the one that **DOES NOT** read default. If you are unfamiliar with keybindings, and have never created one before then the file should be totally empty.

---

Once inside of the ***`keybindings.json`*** file, add the following "JSON" block to the file

```json
// "keybindings.json"

{
  {
    "key": "ctrl+1",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 1
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+2",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 5
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+3",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 10
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+1",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 1
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+2",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 5
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+3",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 10
    }
  },
}
```

> ###### "*The above is only for testing purposes, as the keybindings are simple, and override default VSCode keybindings. You will have to decide which keybindings work best for you, however; if you add the above to your "keybindings.json" file you will get the following* ***Keyboard Shortcuts***"

1. ##### Jump Down a Line      <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
2. ##### Jump Down 5 Lines    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
3. ##### Jump Down 10 Lines  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>
4. ##### Jump Up a Line      <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>
5. ##### Jump Up 5 Lines    <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
6. ##### Jump Up 10 Lines  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

#### For More Help:

---

###### For further assistance Visit the VSCode Commands Page to a list of all commands, or to read specifically about the `cursorMove` command @:

- **[V.S. Code API Commands](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands/) Read the Docs page.**

###### ...or to read about keybindings visit keybindings page that is included the opensource community maintained VSCode documentation collection @:

- **[Creating V.S. Code Keybindings in your *`keybindings.json`* file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)**

---

Comment: @マスターヨーダー Awesome, took me an hour to write that post + the keybindings, so I am really glad it worked. One favor to ask though, would you mind selecting this as the solution that worked for you, to show other people looking for this issue, that this was the  appropriate solution for you.

Comment: If you have shift pressed and run this shortcut it don't keep the selection over where the cursor passed. Is there a way to keep that? So it really works as the arrow moving around in this edge case.

Answer (score 8):

***Disclaimer:** this is not exactly what you wanted, but maybe it will also be useful to know.*

---

The following shortcuts can be used to **insert** new lines in VS Code (repeat them to insert as many lines as needed):

#### Windows / Linux

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Insert line below
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> - Insert line above

#### macOS

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> - Insert line below
- <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> - Insert line above

---

### Useful links for Visual Studio Code

- [Keyboard shortcuts for Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)
- [Keyboard shortcuts for Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)
- [Keyboard shortcuts for macOS](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf)

Comment: Finally, I should have search for this earlier in my web dev career.

Answer (score 0):

From the extension
[Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by-calculation) you can use the `moveby.calculation` command.

**keybindings.json**

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+5",  // or any other key binding
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "args": {
      "lineNrEx": "selection.start.line + 5",
      "charNrEx": "selection.start.character"
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried it.Though some features in this extension worked (like this [move to empty line](https://github.com/rioj7/select-by#move-to-previous-and-next-empty-line)), but the code above you suggest me didn't work.  It seemed that the part 'selection.start.line'  doesn't work.

Comment: @マスターヨーダー the command does not have a default for the `charNrEx` property, where on the line do you want the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @j D3V for his answer.
in new version of vsCode the right syntax for this combination is: forExample : ctrl+numpad1
this is edited json file that @j D3V mentioned in his answer :

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+numpad1",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 1
    }
  }
  ,

  {
    "key": "ctrl+numpad2",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 5
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+numpad3",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "down",
      "value": 10
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+numpad1",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 1
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+numpad2",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 5
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+numpad3",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
      "by": "line",
      "to": "up",
      "value": 10
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no shortcut at the moment to skip multiple lines without extensions. However, `ctrl + shift + o` (by default) or prefixing your search query (`ctrl + p` by default) with an @ can be used to navigate through symbols in a file, which might be what you were looking for.

[image]